# Setting up nginx on Fedora 19

Tags: linux, fedora, webserver, nginx

So I had nginx set-up with the default site. I decided I wanted to change because my website is at `/var/www/server.nyro.net/`... so before I changed again, I went to `127.0.0.1` to see if everything worked. I did. I got the `This page is run by nginx!` and then I decided to edit the conf file.... and now I get 403 forbidden.

I did the chmodd correctly... I don't know what is wrong...

Here is my nginx.conf: http://pastebin.com/cbmvguW1

Here is my nginx.conf **.default**: http://pastebin.com/aWdhv9JR

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `/var/www/server.nyro.net/` empty?

Comment: No. `/var/www/server.nyro.net/` has a simple `index.html` inside it.

Comment: What is result of `ls -ld /var/www/server.nyro.net/`?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x, 2 root root`

Comment: How about `ls -l /var/www/server.nyro.net/`?

Comment: Same.... thing?

Comment: Well, permission seems ok. Try adding index directive to your `location` block anh check.

Comment: I should just start over, huh